# Perform a like and make a friend request without dialog in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, facebook

I've been looking and can not find a valid solution to my problem.
My question is whether it is possible to perform a like to a facebook page, without displaying a dialog, from graphapi or facebook sdk both iOS and Android.
Moreover also I wonder if you can make a friend request in the same way, also for Android and iOS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two tasks are not available programmatically via the Graph API and I doubt they ever will.

The reason is to prevent spam and developers from secretly getting likes on their page.

You must use a Facebook dialog for these actions.